# Undefined Function Fatal Error with Shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode, users, comments

I asked AI ChatGPT:

*Can you develop a wordpress shortcode to create a list of users of a certain role and for each one show if they commented on a certain post (counting how many comments they left)? The shortcode should write a list of users and for each one say: "Yes commented (*number of comments left)*", or "No".*

This is the answer:

```
function my_custom_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'post_id' => 0, // default value for post ID
    'role' => '', // default value for user role
  ), $atts );

  // get the list of users who have commented on the post
  $users = get_users_who_commented( $atts['post_id'], $atts['role'] );

  // generate the output for the shortcode
  $output = '<ul>';
  foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $num_comments = get_number_of_comments_by_user( $atts['post_id'], $user->ID );
    if ( $num_comments > 0 ) {
      $output .= '<li>Yes, commented (' . $num_comments . ' comments)</li>';
    } else {
      $output .= '<li>No</li>';
    }
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'users_who_commented', 'my_custom_shortcode' );
```

<s>he</s> It was so nice to even show me how to use the shortcode.. everything seemed perfect.

```
[users_who_commented post_id="123" role="author"]
```

.. but it doesn't work, "wp-die-message" appears on the page instead of the magic shortcode output. Why?

Can anyone beat the artificial intelligence?
Am I asking the wrong question in the right place?
Thanks

Maybe this can help:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_users_who_commented() in /.../wp-content/themes/responsive/functions.php:1106 Stack trace: #0 /.../wp-includes/shortcodes.php(355): my_custom_shortcode(Array, '', 'users_who_comme...') #1 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #2 /.../wp-includes/shortcodes.php(227): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(uccoun...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '\n<p><span style...') #3 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): do_shortcode('\n<p><span style...') #4 /.../wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('\n<p><span style...', Array) #5 /.../wp-includes/post-template.php(255): apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:paragra...') #6 /.../wp-content/themes/responsive/partials/page/content.php(15): the_content('Leggi altro &#8...') #7 /.../wp-includes/template. in /.../wp-content/themes/responsive/functions.php on line 1106
```

at the end.. it worked:

```
function user_comments_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => 0,
        'role' => '',
    ), $atts );

    // Check if post_id and role are valid
    if ( empty( $a['post_id'] ) || empty( $a['role'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $output = '';

    // Get users of the specified role
    $users = get_users( array( 'role' => $a['role'] ) );

    // Loop through the users
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        // Check if the user has commented on the post
        if ( get_number_of_comments_by_user( $user->ID, $a['post_id'] ) > 0 ) {
            $output .= $user->display_name . ': Yes';
        } else {
            $output .= $user->display_name . ': No';
        }
        $output .= '<br>';
    }

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'user_comments', 'user_comments_shortcode' );
```

```
function get_number_of_comments_by_user( $user_id, $post_id ) {
    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'count' => true,
    ) );

    return $comments;
}
```

the Ai did it.
....I think someone on this site understands the implications of what happened in this question.

Comment: Where is the code for `get_users_who_commented` ?

Comment: Enable error logging & more debugging to see what exactly is breaking.

Comment: I tried pasting the log of what happens

Comment: So I have to think that something is missing in this shortcode regarding "get_users_who_commented"

Comment: note that GPT Chat may have been on WP Tavern recently, but the code that it generated had security flaws and followed some bad practices. The author was very lucky it worked first time. The AI is not writing code, it's just showing you what it imagines the code would look like, sometimes that works, sometimes it merely looks plausible. Otherwise "can you beat the AI" is not really a question, try to avoid hyperbole and state clearly and unambiguously what the question is and phrase it in a way that's specific that can be answered factually

Answer (score 1):

Well, the AI didn't do THAT bad of a job. But either you or the AI didn't deliver code for the functions `get_users_who_commented` or `get_number_of_comments_by_user` which are not wordpress functions but have to be coded seperatly.

Also, i would change the code a bit to use wordpress-internal functions like the comment query:

```
function my_custom_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // default value for post ID: active post
    'role' => '', // default value for user role: none
  ), $atts );
  if( ! $atts['post_id'] || ! ( 'post' == get_post_type($atts['post_id']) ) ){
    //if the post id doesn't exist or is not a post, return nothing
    return "";
  }

  //get a list of all users, if role is set, only of the role
  $user_args = array();
  if( ! empty( $atts['role'] ) ) {
    $user_args['role'] = $atts['role'];
  }
  $users = get_users( $user_args );

  $output = "";
  if( $users ){
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach( $users as $user ){
      // get the count of comments this user has made on this post
      $args = array(
        'type'           => 'comment',
        'post_id'        => (int)$atts['post_id'],
        'user_id'        => $user->ID,
        'number'         => -1,
        'count'          => true
      );
      // The Comment Query
      $number_of_comments = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );
      if( $number_of_comments > 0){
        $output.= '<li>Yes, User '.$user->display_name.' commented (' . $number_of_comments . ' comments)</li>';
      } else {
        $output.= '<li>Sorry, User '.$user->display_name.' did not comment.</li>';
      }
    }
    $output.= '</ul>';
  }
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'users_who_commented', 'my_custom_shortcode' );
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't miss anything in reporting the Ai output, we should think AI forgot to develop that part of the shortcode. Now I try with your code, but from a first attempt it doesn't seem to work: it generates no error, but also no output

Comment: Well, then probably you didn't give it a valid post_id or role i would guess ^^

Comment: I checked, but it doesn't work :( if it's interesting for the community i can keep posting my requests to the AI, now i'm making the recommendation:
please don't forget to program all the functions you use which are not wordpress functions, for example if you use functions like "get_users_who_commented" or "get_number_of_comments_by_user", which are not wordpress functions, you have to code them separately. AI reacted promptly, but there is always something wrong.